# Query is working fine in second execution but taking too much time in first execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a query which is accepting a comma separated string and calculating the sum of transaction. which is working fine as result wise but taking too much time to execute in first attempt. I understand its need tuning but didn't find out the exact reason can any one point me whats wrong with my query.

```
Declare @IDs nvarchar(max)='1,4,5,6,8,9,43,183'

SELECT isnull(isnull(SUM(FT.PaidAmt),0) - isnull(SUM(CT.PaidAmt),0),0) [Amount], convert(char(10),FT.TranDate,126) [Date]
from FeeTransaction FT
Inner Join (
    Select max(P.Id) [Id], P.TranMainId, isnull(SUM(P.AmtToPay),0) [Amt]
    From Patient_Account P
    Group By P.TranMainId
) PA ON FT.Id = PA.TranMainId
Inner Join Patient_Account XP ON PA.Id = XP.Id
Inner Join Master_Fee MF ON XP.FeeId = MF.Id
INNER Join Master_Patient MP ON FT.PID = MP.Id
Inner Join Master_FeeType TY ON MF.FeeTypeId = TY.Id
Left JOIN FeeTransaction CT on FT.TransactionId = CT.TransactionId AND CT.TranDate between '2019'+'08'+'01' and '2019'+'08'+'31' and CT.[Status] <> 'A' AND isnull(CT.IsCancel,0) = 1
Where convert(nvarchar,FT.TranDate,112) between '2019'+'08'+'01' and '2019'+'08'+'31' AND FT.[Status] = 'A' AND XP.FeeId in (SELECT val FROM dbo.f_split(@IDs, ','))
AND isnull(FT.IsCancel,0) = 0 AND FT.EntryBy = 'rajan'
Group By convert(char(10),FT.TranDate,126)
```

Comment: Converting a date to a string in your where clause is bad, SQL Server can't use the index then, and you're using `between` on strings instead of dates. Leave the date field as it is, and use dates for the between values will perform better.

Comment: SQL Monitor can show you a lot of details about the general runtime characteristics of the query.

Comment: And view your execution plan.

Comment: If first run (after long delay) is slow, but subsequent runs are fast(er), then usually SQL has less RAM than optimal AND your query causes lot of disk access. Like other people said, analyze query execution plan, redesign your query to use proper indexes etc; this way you can decrease disk access substantially.

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase the query a bit:

```
select coalesce(SUM(FT.PaidAmt), 0) - coalesce(SUM(CT.PaidAmt), 0)as [Amount],
       convert(char(10),FT.TranDate,126) [Date]
from FeeTransaction FT join
     (select xp.*,
             coalesce(sum(p.amttopay) over (TranMainId), 0) as amt
      from Patient_Account XP ON PA.Id = XP.Id
     ) xp join
     Master_Fee MF 
     on XP.FeeId = MF.Id join
     Master_Patient MP 
     on FT.PID = MP.Id join
     Master_FeeType TY 
     on MF.FeeTypeId = TY.Id left join
     FeeTransaction CT
     on FT.TransactionId = CT.TransactionId and
        CT.TranDate between '20190801' and '20190831' and
        CT.[Status] <> 'A' and
        CT.IsCanel = 1
where FT.TranDate >= '20190801' and and
      FT.TranDate < '20190901' 
      FT.[Status] = 'A' AND
      XP.FeeId in (SELECT val FROM dbo.f_split(@IDs, ',')) and
      (FT.IsCancel = 0 or FT.IsCancel IS NULL) and
      FT.EntryBy = 'rajan'
Group By convert(char(10), FT.TranDate, 126)
```

Then for this version, you specifically an index on `FeeTransaction(EntryBy, Status, TranDate, Cancel)`.

Note the following changes:

- You do not need to aggregate `Patient_Account` as a subquery.  Window functions are quite convenient.
- Your date comparisons preclude the use of indexes.  Converting dates to strings is a bad practice in general.
- You have over-used `isnull()`.
- I assume that the appropriate indexes are in place for the joins.

Answer (score 0):

I would use STRING_SPLIT and Common Table Expressions and do away with date conversions:

```
Declare @IDs nvarchar(max)='1,4,5,6,8,9,43,183'

;WITH CTE_ID AS
(
   SELECT value AS ID FROM STRING_SPLIT(@IDs, ',');)
),
MaxPatient 
AS
(
    SELECT MAX(P.Id) [Id], P.TranMainId, isnull(SUM(P.AmtToPay),0) [Amt]
    From Patient_Account P
    Group By P.TranMainId
)
SELECT  isnull(isnull(SUM(FT.PaidAmt),0) - isnull(SUM(CT.PaidAmt),0),0) As [Amount], 
        convert(char(10),FT.TranDate,126) [Date]
FROM FeeTransaction FT
INNER JOIN MaxPatient PA 
           ON FT.Id = PA.TranMainId
INNER JOIN Patient_Account XP 
           ON PA.Id = XP.Id
INNER JOIN Master_Fee MF 
           ON XP.FeeId = MF.Id
INNER Join Master_Patient MP 
           ON FT.PID = MP.Id
INNER JOIN Master_FeeType TY 
           ON MF.FeeTypeId = TY.Id
INNER JOIN CTE_ID
    ON XP.FeeId = CTE_ID.ID
LEFT JOIN FeeTransaction CT 
           ON FT.TransactionId = CT.TransactionId AND 
              CT.TranDate >= '20190801' AND CT.TranDate < '20190831' AND
              CT.[Status] <> 'A' AND isnull(CT.IsCancel,0) = 1
WHERE FT.TranDate >= '20190801' and FT.TranDate < '20190831' AND 
      FT.[Status] = 'A' AND 
      ISNULL(FT.IsCancel,0) = 0 AND 
      FT.EntryBy = 'rajan'
GROUP BY CAST(FT.TranDate AS Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only is your query slow, but it appear that it is giving incorrect output.

i) When you are not using any column of `Patient_Account` in your `resultset` then why are you writing this sub query?

```
Select max(P.Id) [Id], P.TranMainId, isnull(SUM(P.AmtToPay),0) [Amt]
    From Patient_Account P
    Group By P.TranMainId
```

ii) Avoid using `<>`.So `Status` must be either `'A'` or `'I'` 
     so write  this instead  `CT.[Status] = 'I'`

iii) What is the correct data type of TranDate ?Don't use function in where condition. .

iv) No need of `isnull(CT.IsCancel,0) = 1`,instead write `CT.IsCancel = 1`

So my script is just outline, but it is easy to understand.

```
Declare @IDs nvarchar(max)='1,4,5,6,8,9,43,183'

create table #temp(id int)
insert into #temp(id)
SELECT val FROM dbo.f_split(@IDs, ',')

declare @FromDate Datetime='2019-08-01'
declare @toDate Datetime='2019-08-31'

-- mention all column of FeeTransaction that you need in this query along with correct data type
-- Store TranDate in this manner convert(char(10),FT.TranDate,126) in this table
create table #Transaction()
select * from FeeTransaction FT
where FT.TranDate>=@FromDate and FT.TranDate<@toDate
and exists(select 1 from #temp t where t .val=ft.id)

-- mention all column of Patient_Account that you need in this query along with correct data type
create table #Patient_Account()
Select max(P.Id) [Id], P.TranMainId, isnull(SUM(P.AmtToPay),0) [Amt]
    From Patient_Account P
    where exists(select 1 from #Transaction T where t.id=PA.TranMainId)
    Group By P.TranMainId


    SELECT isnull(isnull(SUM(FT.PaidAmt),0) - isnull(SUM(CT.PaidAmt),0),0) [Amount], TranDate [Date]
    from #Transaction FT
    Inner Join #Patient_Account XP ON PA.Id = XP.Id
    Inner Join Master_Fee MF ON XP.FeeId = MF.Id
    INNER Join Master_Patient MP ON FT.PID = MP.Id
    Inner Join Master_FeeType TY ON MF.FeeTypeId = TY.Id
    Left JOIN #Transaction CT on FT.TransactionId = CT.TransactionId AND CT.[Status] = 'I' AND CT.IsCancel = 1
    Where AND FT.[Status] = 'A' AND XP.FeeId in (SELECT val FROM #temp t)
    AND FT.IsCancel = 0 AND FT.EntryBy = 'rajan'
    Group By TranDate
```